# Maximise the number of new encounters between guests at a meeting

Tags: sql, algorithm, google-sheets, match

I am hosting a series of meetings. There are 24 guests. Two or three times each meeting, we break out into different subgroups of between 2-6 people. I would like to maximise the new encounters so I am looking for an algorithm to help me make new matches, so everyone can meet everyone else.

My current idea is to record the data in Google Sheets and then use the [QUERY function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) to analyse the data. (QUERY is very similar to SQL syntax.)

Here's the 'Round1' table:

```
subgroup1 |  subgroup2
==========|==========
Adam      |  Edith
Ben       |  Fran
Chris     |  Gary
Dave      |
```

And the table for 'Round2' looks like this:

```
subgroup1 |  subgroup2 | subgroup3 
==========|============|===========
Adam      |  Ben       | Dave
Gary      |  Fran      | Edith
Chris     |            |
```

What I want to do is consume that data and output a chart like this which shows me who has met whom:

```
      Adam     Ben     Chris    Dave   Edith   Fran    Gary
Adam   X       TRUE    TRUE     TRUE   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE
Ben   TRUE      X      TRUE     TRUE   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE
Chris TRUE     TRUE     X       TRUE   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE
Dave  etc...
Edith etc...
Fran  etc..
Gary  etc...
```

Could anyone help me to think through how I can use QUERY/SQL to turn those input tables into that output chart?

Comment: Hey Richard,
If you share an editable sample sheet it will be easier to help test and demonstrate solutions for you.

Comment: Thanks Matt, good idea. Here's [an editable demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18SP5w-KLpvjGM_7a5_7030V4_ZSBNUqyXVIKkBjRaSA/edit?usp=sharing) that I made manually. I'd love to be able to write data in the tables on the left and generate the chart on the right automagically.

Comment: Ben met Chris in subgroup1 in the first round

Comment: Gosh, with Covid around, you shoudn't be hosting in-person meetings.

Comment: The meetings are online.

Comment: Someone on Twitter shared this related research: [Hive: Collective Design Through Network Rotation](http://www.niloufar.org/publications/2018/HIVE_CSCW2018.pdf) by NILOUFAR SALEHI, UC Berkeley and MICHAEL S. BERNSTEIN, Stanford University.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in cell B3 on the new tab on your shared sheet called MK.Help, you'll find this single formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((B2:2="")+(ROW(A3:A)>COLUMN(B2:2)),,COUNTIF(QUERY(TRANSPOSE('One table'!A:E),,9),"*"&A3:A&"*"&B2:2&"*")+COUNTIF(QUERY(TRANSPOSE('One table'!A:E),,9),"*"&B2:2&"*"&A3:A&"*")))
```

That is telling you the counts for a heat map based on the tab called OneTable and nothing else.  It will self populate indefinitely as you add groups to the OneTable tab.

Is that what you're going for?

Comment: This is amazing, thanks Matt! It looks right, but I will have to pull it apart to see if I can understand it.

Comment: @RichardDennisBartlett There's a somewhat non-traditional use of QUERY() being used here.  You may be used to seeing query() in it's sql-like implementation of sheets, but for the purposes of the formula i wrote it isn't doing any real "query-ing" at all.  It's just a shortcut to concatenating all the columns of your OneTable tab together.   If you have a few minutes i can try to show you on the sheet.

Comment: Well it took me a few tries but I think I understand this now, thanks for stretching my brain Matt!

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with an answer, with a very laborious process! Maybe if I explain it here, someone can help me think how to make this simpler.

I start with the [example data in this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18SP5w-KLpvjGM_7a5_7030V4_ZSBNUqyXVIKkBjRaSA/edit#gid=455730387).

In the original question I described one table per round, but I don't care in which round someone met, so I can combine all that data into one table. So [in this table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18SP5w-KLpvjGM_7a5_7030V4_ZSBNUqyXVIKkBjRaSA/edit#gid=988706837), each row shows one of the subgroups:

[image: Table showing one subgroup per row]

Then I do a long sequence of match(), transpose(), filter(), join(), split(), until I get [this table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18SP5w-KLpvjGM_7a5_7030V4_ZSBNUqyXVIKkBjRaSA/edit#gid=1625736563) which shows who has met whom:

[image: Table showing who met whom]

From there, it is not so hard to generate the output chart I was looking for

[image: Chart showing which pairs have met]

This works! But it is not very elegant. I will love to make this simpler.